# What hardware configuration do i need to run a workload of 1000 users on jmeter for testing my api

Tags: jmeter

I have an api that returns student data when i send a student id to it .Now I want to test my api with 1000 users hitting every seconds.
My laptop configuration - Core i5 , ram 8 gB
My jmeter completes test but the threads show an error

```
summary +   2642 in 00:00:30 =   88.0/s Avg:   938 Min:    59 Max: 130375 Err:     3 (0.11%) Active: 993 Started: 1000 Finished: 7
Generate Summary Results =  14824 in 00:02:54 =   85.3/s Avg:  1699 Min:    59 Max: 130375 Err:    54 (0.36%)
summary =  14824 in 00:02:54 =   85.3/s Avg:  1699 Min:    59 Max: 130375 Err:    54 (0.36%)
Generate Summary Results +   2636 in 00:00:30 =   87.9/s Avg:   613 Min:    59 Max: 15489 Err:     2 (0.08%) Active: 977 Started: 1000 Finished: 23
Generate Summary Results =  17460 in 00:03:24 =   85.7/s Avg:  1535 Min:        59 Max: 130375 Err:    56 (0.32%)
summary +   2636 in 00:00:30 =   87.9/s Avg:   614 Min:    59 Max: 15489     Err:     2 (0.08%) Active: 977 Started: 1000 Finished: 23
summary =  17460 in 00:03:24 =   85.7/s Avg:  1535 Min:    59 Max: 130375         Err:    56 (0.32%)
:
:
:
:
summary =  17460 in 00:010:24 =   123.7/s Avg:  5535 Min:    59 Max: 130375         Err:    723 (70.3%)
```

By the end around 723 threads failed

My api is returning response if i run the test with 100 users the test is successful but when i run with 1000 users most of the threads get failed or remain active after completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter default configuration is not suitable for high loads, you need to tune it in order to be able to kick off 1000 threads.

1. Make sure to use the [latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) and 64-bit version of [Server JRE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html) or [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. [Increase JVM Heap size allocated to JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) to ~6 gigabytes
3. Disable (or delete) [listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) in Test Plan (if any)
4. Make sure to monitor CPU and RAM usage on the machine where JMeter is running during the test, you can use [JMeter PerfMon plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for that. JMeter must have enough headroom to operate, if it will lack RAM or CPU it will not be able to send requests fast enough. If you see that JMeter machine is overloaded - you will have to consider [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
5. Harwdare requirements will greatly vary depending on your test nature, i.e. number of pre/post processors, assertions, request and response sizes, application response time, etc. so there is no mapping like X hardware = Y virtual users, you will need to assess it for each and every different test plan. Remember to increase the load **gradually** and keep an eye on health metrics

Comment: where do i configure heap size and can you explain the two parameters passed in heap size

Comment: I am using a vrtual machine from alibaba cloud . My server configurations are - 
RAM - 16Gb
Cores - 8
HDD - 50 GB 
I am using the server only for testing the above mentioned load ,will it be sufficient to create those many request 
Note - multi threading is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Lets calculate it using simple math. At max thread size of HTTP request will be approx. 1MB(Apart from payload).

1MB*1000= **1000MB** = 1 GB at-least heap size is required for 1000 concurrent users.

**500 MB** - for additional tasks like listeners, aggregate result

Total is at-least **1500 MB** is required to run this test. configure jmeter to use memory like this in **/apache-jmeter/bin/jmeter** file.

Multithreading is also depends on CPU capability, so try to use multicore CPU.

**What is a thread on a CPU?**
In computer architecture, multithreading is the ability of a central processing unit (CPU) (or a single core in a multi-core processor) to execute multiple processes or threads concurrently, supported by the operating system.

Comment: I am using a vrtual machine from alibaba cloud . My server configurations are - 
RAM - 16Gb
Cores - 8
HDD - 50 GB 
I am using the server only for testing the above mentioned load ,will it be sufficient to create those many request 
Note - multi threading is enabled

Comment: Yes you can simulate pretty good load with these configurations.